# How to talk to an events interface?

Tags: winapi, com

I have a live IDevicePtr, (IDevice is a COM component).

I call a method ("get_DeviceEvents") on it to get its events interface, so now I have a live "IDeviceEvents" object. This object has the following interface:

```
IDeviceEvents : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Raw methods provided by interface
    //

      virtual HRESULT __stdcall add_TalkPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall remove_TalkPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall add_ButtonPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall remove_ButtonPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall add_MuteStateChanged (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall remove_MuteStateChanged (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall add_AudioStateChanged (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall remove_AudioStateChanged (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall add_FlashPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall remove_FlashPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall add_SmartPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall remove_SmartPressed (
        /*[in]*/ IUnknown * value ) = 0;
      virtual HRESULT __stdcall SetInputReport (
        /*[in]*/ SAFEARRAY * reportBuffer ) = 0;
};
```

Say I wanted to intercept the MuteStateChanged event in my application. How do I do that? I can call "add_MuteStateChanged". I assume it's some sort of Event handler adding method. What's the payload I should use? I have a local IDispatch derived object ready to intercept any event with:

```
STDMETHOD(Invoke)(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid,
        LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult,
        EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
    {
        // ALL I want is to get here when some event in IDeviceEvents is fired.
        return S_OK;
    }
```

Background: I've been trying for days now to receive a COM event in a non MFC/ATL C++ Win32 application. It has turned out to be the most difficult task i've ever had to accomplish, time wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a "standard" events implementation. Typically, event source object would expose `IConnectionPointContainer`, `IConnectionPoint` etc. Your interface more looks like implementing events in a different way.

It seems to be expecting you to provide your sink explicitly for events of interest. Note that while this is not a typical COM approach, the whole thing is highly specific to event source implementation. The interface definition does not suggest what exactly interface is expected in `add_MuteStateChanged` argument.

You can do the following. Pass your COM object as an argument to `add_MuteStateChanged`.  `IDispatch` implementation will do fine, it can be actually any COM object - the point here is that it's your code and you can trace all calls on this interface pointer. Check if your event source is querying any interfaces off this `IUnknown`. It should be calling `IUnknown::QueryInterface` immediately or later at the time of event. Having intercepted it, you will see what interface is actually being queried.

If it would be `IDispatch`, the event is likely to be delivered via `IDispatch::Invoke`. Otherwise it is likely to be an interface you need to implement directly.